# Trying to do a batch rename, can't figure out the proper RegEx

Tags: rename, regex, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename my movie collection. All of the files are currently named using dots instead of spaces, i.e. Men.in.Black.avi. I want to replace all of the dots with spaces which isn't terribly difficult, but I need to preserve the last dot for the file extension, i.e. .avi, .mp4, .ogg, etc.

My Googling has provided no solutions. I'm also a Javascript developer  and could see some snazzy applications for it. So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use the [Perl `rename` utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/prename.1.html). The Perl regex `\.(?=.*\.)` matches a dot only when there is another dot later.

```
rename 's/\.(?=.*\.)/ /g' *.*.*
```

If you want to act on files in subdirectories as well:

```
shopt -s globstar    # you can put this in your ~/.bashrc
rename 's/\.(?=.*\.)/ /g' **/*.*.*
```

This works assuming you don't have dots in your directory names. Otherwise I think the simplest method would be to use `find`:

```
find -depth -name '*.*.*' -exec rename 's/\.(?=.*\.)/ /g' {} +
```

Alternatively, using zsh (this only renames regular files and leaves directory names alone, due to the glob qualifier `(.)` at the end):

```
autoload zmv    # you can put this in your ~/.zshrc
zmv -Q '(**/)(*.*)(.[^.]##)(.)' '$1${2//./ }$3'
```

Comment: Once I finally went back and tested it this worked swimmingly. I'm also now using it to dynamically rename some file uploads on my site. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question it occurred to me that I hadn't checked the Ubuntu Software Center. I found an app, pyRenamer, which did a fantastic job of accomplishing my task. I ended up just changing all of the dots to spaces, then changing all instances of the file extensions that were preceded by a space, i.e. " avi", " mp4", " ogg", to replace the spaces with dots. This isn't the best option as there could be a movie with avi or ogg in the title which would be a major pain in the bum, but it did the trick this time.

I'm still interested in the simpler RegEx solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd $movielibrary
rename -n 's/\./ /g;s/ ([^ ]*$)/.$1/' *
```

Does it look good? Rerun the last command without -n.